# log4j Logger is not visible

Tags: java, log4j, project, structure, visibility

Has someone experience with log4j and knows what "the constructor () is not visible means" ?

Here's the code for the Main-class:

```
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;
import stdGame.*;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch( "data/log/myLoggerConfig.xml", 60*1000 );
      new LogTest();
    }
}
```

The LogTest-class is located in stdGame-package, which is already imported as you can see.
The code is working as desired, when placing the LogTest-class in the same package as the Main-class.
Here is the code for the LogTest()-class:

```
package stdGame;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class LogTest {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogTest.class);
    LogTest() {
        logger.info("My info-msg in LogTest.");
        logger.error("My error-msg in LogTest.");
    }
}
```

Try placing them into the same package, the error message will disapear. But i need them placed into seperated packages.

Finally this is the myLoggerConfig.xml-file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
  <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="MeinAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
  <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm" />
  <param name="file" value="data/log/myLogfile.log" />
  <param name="Append" value="true" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
  <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c: %m%n" />
  </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
  <priority value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="MeinAppender" />
  </root>
  </log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class `LogTest` is in `stdName` package and it's constructor has `package-private` access. It seems `Main` class is in some package other than `stdName` and so the compiler is complaining that `LogTest()` constructor is not visible in `Main`'s package. Change the constructor of `LogTest` to public.